# How to notify main thread via pipe if child thread is blocking with socket read?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pipe

### Description of my situation and some code

I've got a main thread processing events in a loop
and a child thread waiting for data on a socket.

The child thread is blocking while waiting for input via socket:

`int n = read(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));`

The received data are written into a temporary buffer with size 1024
and then appended to a global buffer for further processing in the main thread.

If input arrives, the child thread notifies the main thread via pipe:

`write(pipe-write-file-descriptor, some-id, sizeof(int));`

The main thread receives the notification via pipe:

`int n = read(pipe-read-file-descriptor, some-id, sizeof(int));`

The main thread can then process the global buffer's data.

### Possible scenarios

Scenario 1 with bytes received < 1024:
There is no problem. The child thread calls "read-from-socket"
and afterwards "write-to-pipe" in order to notify the main thread.

Scenario 2 with bytes received > 1024:
A loop is needed to let the child thread read all data
(temporary buffer filled with 1024 bytes multiple times
and then appended to the global destination buffer) and only
afterwards call "write-to-pipe" to notify the main thread.

Scenario 3 with bytes received == 1024:
The buffer gets filled once in complete, then the next
loop cycle is waiting for new data on the socket. But because
the reading over socket is blocking and no more input data
are available (1024 bytes have already been received),
the child thread CANNOT NOTIFY the main thread via pipe anymore.

### How to solve or workaround this situation in scenario 3?

Comment: Why can't you change the condition for case 1 to `received <= 1024`?

Comment: When you say "bytes received == 1024", if byte counter is initialized with 0, hope you are counting up to 1023 in your code

Comment: @Vicky Of course I use 0..1023 as index. But the maximum count is 1024.

Comment: @PMF Changing the operator to <= does not help. There could be a next byte following (byte number 1025 with index 1024), so I have to read in a next loop cycle. But in case there is no byte following, the read will block, so I cannot inform the main thread via pipe anymore.

Comment: How do you know how much data there is? You have to know how much bytes you need to read before you notify the other thread. Or you wait until the socket is closed from the remote end (which will also terminate the read)

Comment: @PMF Ok, this helps me. I had hoped there would be a way to receive the bytes on a low level, before processing them in the higher-level application. But obviously, there are only two possibilities: (1) transfer the number of bytes at the beginning of the message or (2) some kind of detectable end-of-message sequence. For e.g. port 80 (HTTP) that means I have to look into the headers and parse them already on a low level to find out the "Content-Length" of the message.

Comment: @ChristianHeller Yes, that's typically required. This is a common problem of binary communication protocols. As you note, there are two ways to work around it: Provide a header with the length at the beginning of each message or have an uniquely identifyable end-of-message marker.